# What role is required to allow MongoDB db.collection.aggregate() usage?

Tags: mongodb, authorization

I have a user in admin.system.users:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "admin.reports", 
    "user" : "reports", 
    "db" : "admin", 
    "credentials" : {
        "MONGODB-CR" : "hash"
    }, 
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read", 
            "db" : "mydb"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am attempting to execute this from a bash script:

```
mongo --quiet mongodb.production.internal/admin -ureports -p"password"  <<< "
var conn = connect('localhost/mydb');
db.auth('reports', 'password');

db.Collection.aggregate([
  {
    \$group: {
      _id: '\$itemId',
      count: { \$sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    \$sort: {
      count: 1
    }
  }
], {cursor: {}}).forEach(function(line) {
  print(line._id+','+line.count);
});
"
```

And I am getting this response from the mongodb instance:
`not authorized on admin to execute command { aggregate:` (amongst other very verbose but pointless output).

What permission do I need to enable the use of the aggregation command for this user? Can it not be done without enabling write access?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not with permissions, `read` is indeed sufficient, but with correctly switching to the right database.

I was using `connect()` to silently (no output) switch to the working db because the `use` command throws output. This is incorrect, and the workaround is in how you specify the connection on the command line, ie:

```
mongo --quiet mongodb.production.internal/mydb --authenticationDatabase admin -ureports -p"password"
```